# What processes of lenition in historical phonology exemplify affrication?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change

Are there any [lenitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition) processes in historical phonology that show affrication? For example, that of the [High German Consonant Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift) where a stop becomes an affricate before becoming a fricative.

E.g.

> *p > pf > f*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other examples abound, although I don't want to just give a long list.

One salient example is the affrication which accompanied palatalization in Romance. In various environments in various languages this took the various forms:

> `k,t → tʃ,ts → ʃ,s,θ`
>   `g,d → dʒ,dz → ʒ,j,x`

e.g. L **cena** `kena` →  [Pt **ceia**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ceia#Portuguese) /sejɐ/, [Es **cena**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cena#Spanish) /θena/, [It **cena**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cena#Italian) /tʃena/, [Ro **cină**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cin%C4%83#Romanian) /ʧinə/, [Ar **tsinã**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsin%C3%A3) /tsinə/

Affrication very often accompanies palatalization, for example in Japanese [t,d → tɕ,dʑ/ts,dz before i/ɯ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#ref_1a); or English t in **question**, **nature**. I understand similar processes have occured in Finnic.

However, it is notable that the diachronic stop->fricative lenition does not always have an affrication stage, and can go right from stop to fricative. An example of this is the [first Germanic consonant shift, Grimm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law):

> `bʰ → b → p → f`
>   `dʰ → d → t → þ`
>   `gʰ → g → k → h`
>   `gʷʰ → gʷ → kʷ → hʷ`

Comment: Nice summary. In Australian English we have a process of palatalisation of stops before the high back vowel /ʊ/, which often results in affricates such as 'dune' /ʤʊn/ (homophonous with 'June'). This is a change in progress, but one day it will be part of the historical phonology of Australian English!

Comment: Is it interesting that in Sardinian we say /kena/? :) At least, in my area (there are some zones). I think the main reason why we kept it, is because of "isolation", considering [Bartoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matteo_Bartoli)'s norms.

Comment: Brilliant summary. @Alenanno very interesting what you say about Sardinian. I was also looking at other cases of lenition and Logudorese popped up - with the lenitive processes that give alterations like l. [ˈfɾad̞ɛ]~[suˈvɾad̞ɛ] and [ˈsaldu]~[suˈzaldu]

Comment: @DangerFourpence Ahah nice! While I know the first one (brother/the brother), I fail to recognize the second word... Logudorese shares a lot with mine, but here and there there are different words.

Comment: @Alenanno I got the examples from a book. [ˈsaldu]~[suˈzaldu] is meant to be Sardinian~the Sardinian if I remember correctly

Comment: @DangerFourpence I see! We use the R instead of L. :)